# Are there any go-to unofficial Rules/Content on DnD 5e post level 20

Tags: dnd-5e

I've looked a bit for posts that ask this question and I found some answers from 2017.

No official post level 20 content or rules were available then, is that still the case now? If so, are there unofficial rulesets generally used by those who want to continue post level 20?

We have essentially saved the world etc etc, but now that we have all this power (and we're a bunch of book nerds who love to ask "what if?") we want to put it to use. Yes we can homebrew everything from scratch, (which is the current plan) but it was asked to "see what the internet can provide" to see if there was another group in the same situation.

Perhaps some new content has come out in the last 5 years or so.

Thank you!

Comment: Howdy and welcome to our stack! You are more than welcome to take the [tour] and you can also visit the [help] for more about how operate.

Comment: As you've noted, this question has been asked before - and that's okay! What we do in this case is close it as a duplicate because it is the same question - but then we can put a bounty on the old question asking if there's new information. That way, everything stays all in one place and if someone searches the way you did, then they'll find it by finding your question. Win-win! You also don't have enough rep to bounty, so I'll go ahead and put one up for you. Just let me know which one you'd like the bounty on!

Comment: I had actually looked at both of those answers lol, the 2nd would be more likely to answer. I know you can get boons and some things, but for stuff like, "I'm a god, how many followers do I need to stay that way." There's just a lot of systems I think we've be reinventing the wheel on.
I ran across a link to the GM'sGuild that might have what I'm looking for. Thank you!

Comment: One final note, "shopping"/"recommendation" type questions are off topic here. Asking if there is anything official is on topic, as those linked questions have done, but asking about unofficial/third party/homebrew solutions would be off topic.